# how can I add a row dynamically

Tags: codenameone

I want to add rows dynamically without disturbing other data in a the table ( data is hardcoded in a `Object[][] dataForTable`. Don't want to persist data in database). I didn't find any method from TableModel or Table itself to do so. Is there any method to achieve this without replacing `Object[][] dataForTable`  or any other way that ?

I have other situation. At any time I want one extra row in the Table that will be empty. And when putting values to this row another empty row will be created dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I re-evaluated this answer and it includes some bugs and conceptual problems. We decided to add the option to add/remove rows from the Table into the [DefaultTableModel](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/table/DefaultTableModel.html). So you can just use ((DefaultTableModel)table).addRow("Col1", "Col2", "Col3"); Just make sure the number of columns is the exact match to the table column count.

**Original answer below:**

The default table model isn't mutable which is probably an omission on our part. Something like this should probably work (haven't tested):

```
public class MyTableModel implements TableModel {
    private ArrayList<Object[]) data;
    private String[] columnNames;
    private EventDispatcher dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    private boolean editable;

    public MyTableModel(String[] columnNames, Object[][] data) {
        this(columnNames, data, false);
    }

    public MyTableModel(String[] columnNames, Object[][] data, boolean editable) {
        this.data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        for(Object[] o : data) {
            this.data.add(o);
        }
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
        this.editable = editable;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public String getColumnName(int i) {
        return columnNames[i];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return editable;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        try {
            return data.get(row)[column];
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException err) {
            // not the best situation but quite useful for the resource editor
            //err.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public void setValueAt(int row, int column, Object o) {
        data.get(row)[column] = o;
        dispatcher.fireDataChangeEvent(column, row);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public void addDataChangeListener(DataChangedListener d) {
        dispatcher.addListener(d);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public void removeDataChangeListener(DataChangedListener d) {
        dispatcher.removeListener(d);
    }

    public void addRow(Object[] row) {
       data.add(row);
       dispatcher.fireDataChangeEvent(-1, row);
    }

}
```

Comment: It worked on dynamically adding row but have issues with `getValueAt(int row, int column)` and `setValueAt(int row, int column, Object o)`. Method `getValueAt(int row, int column)`  throwing exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` only once and  `setValueAt(int row, int column, Object o)`  method sometime sets value for other cells as well when trying to add/change value in a cell. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: If you don't figure it out just post a question with the stack traces and problematic lines highlighted.

Comment: I need little bit background on `fireDataChangeEvent(int index, int type)` method of `EventDispacher.class` . How `index` and `type` in the line `dispatcher.fireDataChangeEvent(column, row);` of `setValueAt(int row, int column, Object o)` method relevent with column and row of Table. And same with `dispatcher.fireDataChangeEvent(-1, row);` in `addRow(Object[] row)` method.

Comment: These two methods are causing problems.

Comment: I think column might need to be 0 and not -1. fireDataChangeEvent is used to notify the view (Table) of changes in the model.

Comment: I don't know why but calling  `public void addRow(Object[] row)`  method first time does nothing. If called this method again then a row added to the table.

Comment: That might be a bug in table, you can open an issue on that. We'll have a look.